# Webpack/Browserify and UI-Router

Tags: angularjs, browserify, webpack

I can't seem to get Webpack or Browserify to work with UI-Router. Can anybody help?

Here is my module file:

```
"use strict";

require("angular");

angular
    .module("app", [require("angular-ui-router")])
    .config(require("./app.routes"));
```

And my file for the routes:

```
"use strict";

module.exports = function($urlRouteProvider, $stateProvider) {
    $urlRouteProvider.otherwise("/state1");

    $stateProvider
        .state("state1", {
            url: "/state1",
            templateUrl: "partials/state1.html"
        })
        .state("state2", {
            url: "/state2",
            templateUrl: "partials/state2.html"
        });
}
```

Comment: Why do people keep talking about Bower in the answers here? I see nothing related to bower at all in the question.

Comment: what happens when you run it ?

Answer (score 1):

So sadly when you combine bower and the angularjs dependency injection system, quite frequently  a component won't use the same bower package name as it's angular module name. This is completely annoying and frustrating, but it is sadly quite common. In this case, the bower component named "angular-ui-router" declares itself with angular module name "ui.router", which is also what it exports in commonjs. **So**:

In your `package.json` "browser" section, configure it like this:

```
"ui.router": "./bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js",
```

Then in your browser code, you can both `require` it (so browserify includes it in your bundle) and inject it into your angular app at the same time (this is a bit advanced/confusing, but it happens to be supported by this particular module, whereas most angular js add-ons in bower don't have any support for commonjs baked in).

```
angular.module("app", [require("ui.router")]);
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use bower with webpack, you need a line like this: https://github.com/jeffling/angular-webpack-example/blob/master/template/webpack.config.coffee#L83

This will teach webpack to read the `main` property in `bower.json` files. This works for angular-ui-router - I use it on our projects.

Comment: The OP didn't mention bower at all. He might be using angular-ui-router from npm.